# email template to be used in apex . Email template used approval.id

Tags: apex, email, email-template

I am trying to send emails through email template in my apex class .
This is the code I am trying

```
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
mail.setToAddresses(emailaddress);
mail.setTargetObjectId(user.id);
mail.setTemplateId('00Xf0000000cE9E');//template salesforce id 
Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {
            mail
         });
           }
```

I am still not able to figure out where can I use approval id so that the values in template fetches details as per that .

My email template uses Approval related details such as approval.name,approval_status etc and displays it in a table .

Now I am trying to pass the template in the trigger which fires when status is updated to submitted or rejected or cancelled .So i am using trigger.new[0].id which is approval id in the trigger .So how can I pass this id so that template fetches approval related details on the basis of it .

Also if I use email templates can I send it to external ids too in apex because there is a set.targetobjectid() method which takes ids of salesforce users . not sure how to bypass this mandatory targetobjecid

Comment: This question needs some elaboration. What does your email template look like and what triggers this Apex code. Use [edit], not comments to elaborate.

Comment: @cropredy thanks for asking . Please check now

Comment: please use [edit] and add in the email template (is it VF?) - just the first line and a couple of relevant merge fields. Is there a WhatId/relatedToType?